# Image storage performance on file system with Nodejs and Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My `Node.js` application currently stores the uploaded images to the file system with the paths saved into a `MongoDB` database. Each document, maybe max 2000 in future, has between 4 and 10 images each. I don't believe I need to store the images in the database directly for my usage (I do not need to track versions etc), I am only concerned with performance.

Currently, I store all images in one folder and associated paths stored in the database. However as the number of documents, hence number of images, increase will this slow performance having so many files in a single folder?

Alternatively I could have a folder for each document. Does this extra level of folder complexity affect performance? Also using MongoDB the obvious folder naming schema would be to use the ObjectID but does folder names of the length (24) affect performance? Should I be using a custom ObjectID?

Are there more efficient ways? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simply accessing files, the number of items in a directory does not really affect performance.  However, it is common to split out directories for this as getting the directory index can certainly be slow when you have thousands of files.  In addition, file systems have limits to the number of files per directory.  (What that limit is depends on your file system.)

If I were you, I'd just have a separate directory for each document, and load the images in there.  If you are going to have more than 10,000 documents, you might split those a bit.  Suppose your hash is `7813258ef8c6b632dde8cc80f6bda62f`.  It's pretty common to have a directory structure like `/7/8/1/3/2/5/7813258ef8c6b632dde8cc80f6bda62f`.

Comment: Thanks Brad, perfect! so using an ObjectID despite its length is actually not an issue?

Comment: @NinjaPants, Correct, file name length has no bearing on performance.